# PDO LIMIT with default function value

Tags: php, mysql, limit

I have a method which takes number of items & start from as limit and returns the value

```
public function comment_recent_comments_block($numbers = 10, $start_from = 1) {

    $sql = " SELECT comment.comment_id, comment.subject,
             content.content_id, content.content_type_id
                    FROM comment
                    LEFT JOIN content ON content.content_id = comment.reference_id 
                    WHERE comment.reference_table = 'content'
                    AND comment.subject IS NOT NULL AND comment.subject !='' ";
    $sql .=" ORDER BY comment.weightage DESC, comment.creation_date DESC ";
    $sql .= " LIMIT :lmt_start_from , :lmt_no_of_records  ";
```

....rest of the code...
}

I expect PHP to consider 10 & 1 as default values but it does not work. My sql throws error showing error at 'NULL' value.
Now, if I explicitly check the parameters and set the values such as

```
$numbers = empty($numbers) ? 10 : $numbers;
$start_from = empty($start_from) ? 1 : $start_from;
```

with in the method then it works.

Can any explain me what I am missing in the first method. why PHP doesnt consider the default values...I have tried entering as string '10' & '1' but that didnt work either

Thanks

---------------------------------------complete code---------------------------------

```
 public function findBySql($sql, $value_a = '') {
    global $dbc;
    $stmt = $dbc->connection->prepare(" $sql ");
    if (!empty($value_a)) {
     foreach ($value_a as $key => $value) {
        if (!empty($value)) {
         if ($key == 'lmt_no_of_records' || $key == 'lmt_start_from') {
            $stmt->bindValue(":$key", $value, PDO::PARAM_INT);
         } else {
            $stmt->bindValue(":$key", $value);
         }
        } else {
         $stmt->bindValue(":$key", NULL);
        }
     }
    }
    try {
     $stmt->execute();
     $result = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_CLASS);
     return $result;
    } catch (PDOException $e) {
     echo "Record couldnt be fetched !!: " . $e->getMessage();
     return 0;
    }
 }



public function comment_recent_comments_block($numbers = 10, $start_from = 1) {
    $numbers = empty($numbers) ? 10 : $numbers;
    $start_from = empty($start_from) ? 1 : $start_from;
    $sql = " SELECT comment.comment_id, comment.subject,
             content.content_id, content.content_type_id
                    FROM comment
                    LEFT JOIN content ON content.content_id = comment.reference_id 
                    WHERE comment.reference_table = 'content'
                    AND comment.subject IS NOT NULL AND comment.subject !='' ";
    $sql .=" ORDER BY comment.weightage DESC, comment.creation_date DESC ";
    $sql .= " LIMIT :lmt_start_from , :lmt_no_of_records  ";
    $value_a = ['lmt_no_of_records' => $numbers, 'lmt_start_from' => $start_from ];

    $result = $this->findBySql($sql, $value_a);
        $comment_string = '';
    if (count($result) > 0) {
     $comment_string .= '<ul class="documentation_list comment">';
     foreach ($result as $records) {
        $comment_string .= '<li class="comment_subject">';
        $comment_string .= '<a href="' . HOME_URL . 'content.php?mode=2&' . 'content_id=' . $records->content_id .
                        '&content_type_id=' . $records->content_type_id . '#comment_id_' . $records->comment_id . '">';
        $comment_string .= $records->subject . '</a>';
        $comment_string .= '</li>';
     }
     $comment_string .= '</ul>';
    }

    return $comment_string;
 }
```

Now this working but if I remove below two statements
    $numbers = empty($numbers) ? 10 : $numbers;
    $start_from = empty($start_from) ? 1 : $start_from;
It wont work

Comment: there is something with the rest of your code

Comment: please share function calling code

Comment: Pleas post the part where you are defining `:lmt_start_from` and `:lmt_no_of_records`, meaning the bind_param/value and execute call.

Comment: Another thing I just noticed: Is "My sql throws error showing error at 'NULL' value" from the error message? You should always post the complete error message to help the diagnosis. If this is from the error message the problem might not be in your LIMIT at all. Is comment.subject nullable? Please add your table structure and the complete error message to the question as well.

Comment: added the complete function in a new comment... I didnt initially post the whole code because most complain why are warping PDO w/o understanding the requirement & logic... Thanks again

Answer (score 0):

The code you've posted has nothing PDO specific in it and I assume the problem hasn't nothing to do with it either (but it's possible).
Please try something like

```
<?php
class Foo {
    public function comment_recent_comments_block($numbers = 10, $start_from = 1) {
            // put the following three lines of code at the beginning of your method comment_recent_comments_block
        var_export(debug_backtrace(0, 1));
        var_export( array($numbers, $start_from) );
        die;
    }
}

$foo = new Foo;
$foo->comment_recent_comments_block();
```

the output in my case is

```
array (
  0 => 
  array (
    'file' => 'something.php',
    'line' => 11,
    'function' => 'comment_recent_comments_block',
    'class' => 'Foo',
    'type' => '->',
    'args' => 
    array (
    ),
  ),
)array (
  0 => 10,
  1 => 1,
)
```

which indiciates that the method really has been called without parameters and the respective default values have been assigned to $numbers and $start_from.
What's your output?

Comment: Thanks VolkerK, I 'll check this and what you pointed out is quite logical.